# Border artefact in GLSL pixelate shader

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I am doing a simple pixelate shader in GLSL.
Everything is working as expected except for this border artifact that I see at pixelation borders.

The code is:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D Texture0;
uniform int pixelCount;
varying vec2 fTexCoord;

void main(void)
{
   float pixelWidth = 1.0/float(pixelCount);

   float x = floor(fTexCoord.x/pixelWidth)*pixelWidth + pixelWidth/2.0;
   float y = floor(fTexCoord.y/pixelWidth)*pixelWidth + pixelWidth/2.0;

   gl_FragColor = texture2D(Texture0, vec2(x, y));
}
```

Please see the attached image.

I am clueless on why this is happening.
Please help me with this...

[image: Border artifact between pixelations.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is related to texture interpolation.

Are you using `GL_NEAREST` for your texture samplers (this makes the texture sampler use point sampler instead of some interpolation)?

```
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST );
```

Also you should probably not use mipmaps.

It would also be useful to know how the actual texture image looks like and how the geometry looks like (I assume you are rendering a single quad).

Comment: You were right about Mipmaps.<br> Filtering is not the issue. but mipmaps are. <br>But I still dont understand why mipmaps make this artefact. Could someone please explain the theory behind this?

Comment: The problem is that when generating mipmaps (such as gluBuild2DMipmaps), the function uses some kind of interpolation to get good looking downscaled images. But in a few cases this doesn't work: Sometimes you want to keep sharp edges (like you) and sometimes the values in the textures are not colors and cannot use linear interpolation (which is the case then the texture stores a normal map). In these cases you must generate the mipmap levels manually (or not use mipmaps at all).

Comment: Thanks Mortennobel. <br/> My curious mind is still having questions. <br/>If it is because of filtered texels from a mipmap, then why is the artifact confined to just the borders. A mipmap level should serve pixels over some continuous region until the  texels are small enough for the next level of mipmap; right?

Comment: I would still like to know if your screenshot contains just a single quad - or 9 quads? Also I'm assuming that your texture is only RGB and not RGBA (with an alpha value).

Comment: To answer your last question: Yes, mipmapping serves the pixel value from the nearest mipmap level (or interpolate between the two nearest mipmap levels). Anyway checkout the following links - this might help you: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_Texture and http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Automatic_mipmap_generation

Comment: Thanks Mortennobel. It is a single quad; and texture is in RGB format.